# Get Outlook.PropertyPageSite so you can call OnStatusChange() and update UI

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

The outlook [`PropertyPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.propertypage.aspx) Interface requires a Read Only Boolean Property `Dirty`.

When this is set to `true`, the Apply button from the property page options dialog will become enabled.

[image: Apply]

According to this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864286.aspx), you have to call [`OnStatusChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869275(v=office.14).aspx) to notify the UI that the value of `Dirty` has changed.

Purportedly, this is available by calling the following:

```vb
Dim ppSite As Outlook.PropertyPageSite = Parent
ppSite.OnStatusChange()
```

But `Parent` always returns nothing so I have no mechanism to tell the UI when I have updated the dirty flag.

How can I do this?

---

I'm using the basic steps produced in this [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7dd6f82-13e7-4a28-8316-9c535eaa7518/customize-outlook-options-dialog?forum=vsto#3e9cf09c-8056-46d3-bb09-2da019cf8ba6) to setup the options page.
Here's a full implementation of my code:

#### Added New User Control called `SendReminderOptions`:

```vb
<ComVisible(True)>
Public Class SendReminderOptions : Inherits UserControl : Implements Outlook.PropertyPage

    Const captionDispID As Integer = -518

    Private _dirty As Boolean = False
    Public ReadOnly Property Dirty As Boolean Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage.Dirty
        Get
            Return _dirty
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub SetDirty(newValue As Boolean)
        _dirty = newValue
        Dim ppSite As Outlook.PropertyPageSite = Parent
        ppSite.OnStatusChange()
    End Sub

    <DispId(captionDispID)> _
    Public ReadOnly Property PageCaption() As String
        Get
            Return "Send Reminder Options"
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub GetPageInfo(ByRef HelpFile As String, ByRef HelpContext As Integer) Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage.GetPageInfo

    End Sub

    Public Sub Apply() Implements Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PropertyPage.Apply

    End Sub

End Class
```

#### Added the following code to `ThisAddIn`

```vb
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    AddHandler myOutlook.OptionsPagesAdd, AddressOf AddOptionsPage
End Sub

Private Sub AddOptionsPage(ByVal pages As PropertyPages)
    pages.Add(New SendReminderOptions(), "Options")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function gets the parent `PropertyPageSite` Object using Reflection. It must be called in Load event.

**Visual Basic**

```vb
Private Function GetPropertyPageSite() As Outlook.PropertyPageSite
    Dim objType As Type = GetType(System.Object)
    Dim assemblyPath As String = objType.Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("mscorlib.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll").Replace("file:///", "")
    Dim assemblyName As String = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath).FullName

    Dim unsafeNativeMethods As Type = Type.[GetType](System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assemblyName, "System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods"))
    Dim oleObjectType As Type = unsafeNativeMethods.GetNestedType("IOleObject")

    Dim methodInfo As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = oleObjectType.GetMethod("GetClientSite")
    Dim propertyPageSite As Object = methodInfo.Invoke(Me, Nothing)

    Return DirectCast(propertyPageSite, Outlook.PropertyPageSite)
End Function
```

**CSharp**

```cs
private Outlook.PropertyPageSite GetPropertyPageSite()
{
    Type objType  = typeof(System.Object);
    string assemblyPath = objType.Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("mscorlib.dll", "System.Windows.Forms.dll").Replace("file:///", "");
    string assemblyName = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(assemblyPath).FullName;

    Type unsafeNativeMethods = Type.GetType(System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(assemblyName, "System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods"));
    Type oleObjectType = unsafeNativeMethods.GetNestedType("IOleObject");

    System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo = oleObjectType.GetMethod("GetClientSite");
    Object propertyPageSite = methodInfo.Invoke(this, null);

    return (Outlook.PropertyPageSite)propertyPageSite;
}
```

From [How to implement OL PropertyPage](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=978) / [Customize Outlook Options Dialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7dd6f82-13e7-4a28-8316-9c535eaa7518/customize-outlook-options-dialog?forum=vsto#c45f5fb1-c15d-4a5e-bf0e-7cb677462fdd)

Comment: Any thoughts on how you might get the Window handle? Trying to set the parent for a WPF window, but the PropertyPageSite doesn't have a Handle property.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan, which Handle?  The Handler for the page load event?  You might want to ask another question with the full set of details and link to this one.

Comment: The Window handle, `IntPtr`. Not event handler.